# Get Items from QVariantList with Qt

Tags: qt

I am using ActiveX to kick Excel from Qt and I retrieved the data array using a specific range. The datatype is QVariant but in the debugger it is written "QVariant(QVariantList)". It has around 1000 items, how can I access/get these items ?

Here is the code I produced.

```
QAxObject* excel = new QAxObject( "Excel.Application", 0 );
QAxObject* workbooks = excel->querySubObject( "Workbooks" );
QAxObject* workbook = workbooks->querySubObject( "Open(const QString&)", filename );
QAxObject* sheets = workbook->querySubObject( "Worksheets" );
QAxObject* sheet = sheets->querySubObject( "Item( int )", 1);
QAxObject* range = sheet->querySubObject("Range(A2:A1002)");
QVariant data = range->dynamicCall("value"); // the data I want to retrieve
```

Answer (score 1):

```
QVariant data = range->dynamicCall("value");
QVariantList list = data.toList();
for (/*const*/ auto &v : list) {
    /// work with QVariant v
}
```

From the Qt Docs:

> The QVariant class acts like a union for the most common Qt data
> types.

"most common Qt data types" includes QVariantList. So if you are sure that your QVariant is of type QVariantList, you can use the member function of QVariant to cast it to a QVariantList. If you are not entirely certain that your QVariant is actually a QVariantList, you should use *QVariant.canConvert(targetTypeId)* to verify before you call *QVariant.toList()*.

Comment: May be better use for (/*const*/ auto &v : list) ?

Comment: You are probably correct, however it depends on the implementation of the activeX backend, which I dont know, but it doesnt return a const value. Maybe changing the value of the QVariant will change the actual worksheet?

Comment: Thank you but looking at the debugger, the variable v is a QVariant & containing one item. The item is a double, how can I get the double. Sorry if it is a basic question. v.toDouble() returns 0.

Comment: double QVariant::toDouble(bool *ok = nullptr) const.      What does ok return?

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @Vasilij The boolean ok pointer returs false so the conversion failed. There is no simple way to get an item from a specific index like v[0] (for the first item) ?

Comment: @oro777, if ok is false, then most probably this QVariant entity is empty. Try to convert it to a string and print it out. The error is somewhere else most probably.

Comment: @Vasilij, thanks, my post has been hidden. The QVariant entity is not empty, it is a QVariantList containing one item. So the original data is a QVariantList containing multilple items which are QVariantList.

Comment: If v in the loop is the QVariantList containing one item, then you can try this: auto value = v.at(0).toDouble();